# I accidentally copied a bash file replacing it with the .bashrc file in my Linux Mint. How am I supposed to retrieve the .bashrc file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-mint

I was trying to place my bash file to the bin, but i copied the contents to the `.bashrc` file, replacing the contents of the original file. I would like you to help me get back the .bashrc file.

Comment: Unless you backed up your original .bashrc file, it's gone for good.

Comment: You can't - it's lost...

Comment: Strictly speaking, it depends on your file system. Some take periodic snapshots, allowing you to recover older versions of a file. In general, though, yes, the file is gone.

Comment: If you've not modified it from what you got when you created your account, the `/etc/skel` directory will have the original.

Comment: Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot recover your custom `.bashrc`. But, if you want to restore it to the default `.bashrc`, you will find the one copied when creating a new user in:

```
/etc/skel/.bashrc
```